# Views contextual filter base path URL relative to current path

Tags: views

How can I get the summary base URL to start with the node that the view is currently on?

Below is my current configuration

[image: Taxonomy term ID config]

[image: OG Contextual Filter Config]

If I am understanding correctly, 'node/%' in the base path for the summary is telling it to use the argument from my organic group contextual filter.

I need to use the Node ID of the current Node that the view is applied to but keep the rest of the functionality the same.

Let me know what other information I need to supply.

Comment: I was able to get a step further with this problem.
I added the contextual Filter Global: Null with "Provide Default Value: Content ID form URL"

This made the path relative to the page the view is applied to but appends the organic groups ID to the end which I haven't figured out how to resolve.